# Sending data from one VF to another with single controller

Tags: apex

I have a requirement. I have created one VF which displays all record of a custom object with checkboxes and I am creating one list of selected record(based on the selected checkbox). lastly, I want to create PDF which holds all selected record. So for PDF, I have created another VF(renderAs=pdf) which I am referencing from one method of the controller. Both VF shares one controller. in the method I have written below.

```
public pagereference getPdf(){
    pagereference pager=page.name;
    pager.setredirect(true);
    return pager;
}
```

but the problem is,  when I put setredirect as true.. it is flushing selected record list and PDF generates with no value.

How can I pull selected list to PDF?

Comment: It also depends on what is defined in the constructor of the class.  Please post that code as well.

Comment: The relevant VF doc for this comes from the [Wizard example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_wizard.htm?search_text=wizard)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `pager.setredirect(false);` instead of `pager.setredirect(true);`

`setredirect()` Sets the value of the PageReference object's redirect attribute. If set to true, a redirect is performed through a client side redirect that's why it does not transfer the view state otherwise it does.

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm)

Comment: Please add more clarification on why this is the correct answer or any further details you can on the solution. This is currently a low quality answer as there is only a statement with no facts backing it up.

Comment: updated, I hope it satisfies.